# Show that improper integral converges using taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, taylor-expansion, improper-integrals

> Show that the improper integral
> \begin{align*}
> \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\sin\left(t\right) }{t}\mathrm{~d}t 
> .\end{align*}
> converges.

My attempt:
Determining the Taylor series of $\sin\left(t\right) $  around $0$ yields
\begin{align*}
\sin\left(t\right)= t - \frac{\sin\left(\xi\right) }{2}t^{2}, \quad t, \xi \in [0, 1]
\end{align*}
which allows for the conclusion
\begin{align*}
0\le \sin\left(t\right) \le t, \quad t \in [0, 1]
.\end{align*}
Thus, using the comparison test, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin\left(t\right) }{t}
\le \int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{d}t 
\iff \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin\left(t\right) }{t}\le 1
.\end{align*}
Hence, the integral converges by the comparison test, using the additional fact that
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin\left(t\right) }{t}\mathrm{~d}t 
\end{align*}
clearly converges.
Is my attempt correct?

Comment: As written, your biimplication speaks to $x \in [0,1]$, but this constraint does not appear in the problem statement.

Comment: @EricTowers it's given that $x > 0$, would it be sufficient if I added that $\sin(t) / t$ on the interval $[1, x]$ is a uniformly continuous function and hence integrable over this interval?

Comment: @Richard Use Remann integration argument.